# Understanding uncaughtException event in Node.js

Tags: node.js

In my below example, moduleA1 does not exists , and since the module does not exists I was expecting the 'uncaughtException' listner to get executed, but that is not happing.

```
'use strict';

// this module does not exist    
var moduleA = require('./moduleA/moduleA1');

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
console.log("Error Message: " , err.message);
process.exit(1);
});
```

I would like to know in what scenarios ''uncaughtException' code will be executed

Comment: The reason it's not happening is that you're trying to attach the listener *after* the error has already occurred and the process has exited. Attach the listener first.

Comment: what you said is correct , now it's working